# nonexclusive wait queue add process to head while exclusive tail, why?

Tags: linux, kernel

While reading linux source code, I have read the following code:

`void fastcall add_wait_queue(wait_queue_head_t *q, wait_queue_t *wait)
{
    unsigned long flags;

    wait->flags &= ~WQ_FLAG_EXCLUSIVE;
    spin_lock_irqsave(&q->lock, flags);
    __add_wait_queue(q, wait);
    spin_unlock_irqrestore(&q->lock, flags);
}
EXPORT_SYMBOL(add_wait_queue);

void fastcall add_wait_queue_exclusive(wait_queue_head_t *q, wait_queue_t *wait)
{
    unsigned long flags;

    wait->flags |= WQ_FLAG_EXCLUSIVE;
    spin_lock_irqsave(&q->lock, flags);
    __add_wait_queue_tail(q, wait);
    spin_unlock_irqrestore(&q->lock, flags);
}
EXPORT_SYMBOL(add_wait_queue_exclusive);`

The difference is between __add_wait_queue() and __add_wait_queue_tail().
Why the implementaion differs in this step?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In exclusive case, only the first process will be woken up, so it must be the one waiting longest.

In non-exclusive all processes are going to be woken up, so the order does not matter and inserting to head is easier for singly-linked list.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It seems the wait queue is impemented with doubly-linked list, as my version 2.6.11.

Comment: @wilsonwen: Than it's probably simply the version that looks more default in the case where the order isn't important.